# Visual Basic .NET Power Pack 2003

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone point me to a link to download the Power Pack mentioned at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289491(VS.71).aspx?  I'm aware that there is a later version, i need this one.  Unfortunately, the Gotdotnet websites where this was hosted are not longer available.

Thanks in advance,

Richard Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened to Gotdotnet was quite ugly, lots of valuable stuff disappeared for good.  Ken Tucker preserved the source code for that power pack, download it from [this url](http://www.vb-tips.com/downloads/vbpowerpacksource.zip).

Comment: Hello Hans, thank you very much, i greatly appreciate it!  Many thanks to Ken Tucker as well.